# Create c# class with a table. Sqlite-net

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, windows-runtime

I have SQLite database in isolated storage in Windows Store App.
I use `SQLite for Windows Runtime`

My class:

```
[Table("Projects")]
public class Project
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [Column ("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("group_id")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I get data from web server and put it to local `DataBase`.
When I try to store data to `DataBase`, I handled exeption

```
 e.message = table Projects has no column named Name
```

because `DataBase` haven't column "Name"

My question is: How to use one class with fields, maping to `DataBase Column` and simple fields? (I wont not include some fields to `DataBase`, but I need it in class.)

**UPD.**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[NotMapped]
public string Name { get; set; }

Error The type or namespace name 'NotMappedAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

When I try to add `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` Error: `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll could not be added. This component is already automaticaly referenced by the build system`.

Comment: Which ORM are you using? So form where are the `Table` and `PrimaryKey` etc attributes come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using the [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library in this case you need to use the `SQLite.IgnoreAttribute`

```
[SQLite.Ignore]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but I'd try it already. Check updated question.